# PyMongo is deleting instead of updating document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using MongoDB to maintain a list of broadcast locations and
the geolocation of their antennas.

I'm using pymongo to push the locations to an array like `[{lat: nnn.dd, lon: nnn.dd}, {lat: nnn.dd, lon: nnn.dd}]`

I'm reading a file of location data.  My update looks like this:

```
stations.update(
    {"facility-id": fac_id},
    {"$push": {"antennas": {"lat": lat, "lon": lon}}}
)
```

The first time this update runs on a given facility id it does indeed update the document in the database correctly. But a second update for the same facility ID deletes the document entirely.

Why does this happen? I want to add the new coordinates to the antennas array.

Note, duplicate geocoordinates are ok.

Per the comments here is a program. Run it once and the existing document is updated. Run it again and the document is deleted:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

dbname="test"
db = client[dbname]
stations = db.stations
lat=456.45
lon=-321.90
fac="2"
stations.update(
    {"facility-id": fac},
    {"$push": {"antennas": {"lat": lat, "lon": lon}}}
)

print 'done'
```

Comment: I would supect you are actually using the "upsert" option and what in fact is happening is an entirely new document is being created for a different "facility-id" than the last update. To make the problme clear you really need to show the wider context of code where this is being called. Also log and check all variable input to be sure that it is indeed what you expect. Add the wider code context to your question if you still have problems.

Comment: It works fine when I try this code; it keeps adding another `antennas` element to the existing doc each time I run it.